# Accessibility order

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, ios9

We have a project where we want to change the order of accessibility based on the tags of the subviews. I am trying to find examples but I am not able to find any examples with swift. Can any one help me with this?

Thanks,
Shabri

Answer (score 0):

We cannot change the order of accessibility. Based on DOM appearence the screen reader will read the content